# Javascript - How to assign the first element of an object in array to be the key of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Basically I have an array with:

that I fill with an SQL query. This makes the array like:

I want to create another array where the key of the array objects is the first element of the objects inside organisations, so they would be id1, id2 etc etc.

I think the output should be like:

```
newArray = [id1: {name1, type2}, id2: {name2, type2}]
```

Comment: May you add an example of the output you want?

Comment: `organisation_ids = organisations.map(x => x.id)` ?

Comment: Are your IDs always starting from 0 and go up sequentially? If not, maybe you should just `sort` the Array: `organisations.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)`, so you dont have to rely on the 'key', which should be sequential in an array, otherwise its an object.

Comment: the ids start from 1 and auto increment however rows in the DB can be deleted so some ids will eventually be deleted and therefore leave gaps

Comment: Arrays don't have keys. They have indexes. Do you mean `Set` or sth [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). And your array notation is not valid. It can be like this :`[ {id1: {name1, type2}}, {id2: {name2, type2}}]`, but i'm not sure it is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try that one

```
     const a = [
        { id: 1, name: "peter", city: "New City" },
        { id: 2, name: "alex", city: "New City" },
        { id: 3, name: "michael", city: "New City" }
      ];

      const b = a.map(item => {
        const { id, ...others } = item;

        return { id: { ...others } };
      });

      console.log(b);
```

Comment: The result will be an array with index values `0,1,2`: as shown here: `[{"id":{"name":"peter","city":"New City"}},{"id":{"name":"alex","city":"New City"}},{"id":{"name":"michael","city":"New City"}}]`. The `id` values `1,2,3` are nowhere to be found in the resulting array.

Comment: @cars10m Arrays don't have keys. They have indexes. If we have [id1, id2, id3] we lost the other part of the data. If we wanna get the key in that structure [id: {...}], we can use Object.keys() method.

Comment: Hi Carsten, If the first element is the same like we have two objects with the same Id (11) { id: 11, name: "peter", city: "New City" }, { id: 11, name: "peter111", city: "New City111" }, in this case, this is not working. I want the result like "11": [{}, {}]

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of Petia's solution. @Petia: I hope you don't mind me copying your sample data.

```js
const a = [
        { id: 11, name: "peter", city: "New City" },
        { id: 12, name: "Alex", city: "Another City" },
        { id: 31, name: "Michael", city: "Third City" }
      ], b = {};
a.forEach(obj=>{b[obj.id]=obj});

console.log(b);
```

In this solution the resulting object of objects will still have the `id` property as part of the listed objects. If required, these `id` properties can easily be removed by means of the following expression:

```
Object.values(b).forEach(obj=>{delete obj.id});
```

Comment: Hi Carsten,
If the first element is the same like we have two objects with the same Id (11)
{ id: 11, name: "peter", city: "New City" }, { id: 11, name: "peter111", city: "New City111" },
in this case, this is not working.

I want the result like "11": [{}, {}]

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you are asking but assuming that your objects contain variables and not strings this might help.

```js
id1=1;
name1='bob'
type1='ajax'

id2=2;
name2='sid'
type2='comet'

org = [ {id1, name1,type1}, {id2, name2, type2}]


neworg={}
for(i=0;i<org.length;i++){

   id = Object.values(org[i])[0]  
   
   arr=new Array();
   
   for (j=1;j<Object.keys(org[i]).length;j++){
     arr.push(Object.values(org[i])[j])   
   }

    neworg[id]={arr}


}

console.log(neworg)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` operator:

```
const result = a.map(s => ({[s.id]:{...s}}));
```

And the example:

```js
const a = [
        { id: 10, name: "Science", Type: "Type 1" },
        { id: 20, name: "Management", Type: "Type 2" },
        { id: 30, name: "Sport", Type: "Type 3" }
      ];

const result = a.map(s => ({[s.id]:{...s}}));
console.log(result);
```